# Python linked-list issues of receiving memory addresses when printing unless double calling

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am creating a Linked List implementation and I cannot fix this error of having to double call `node.val.val` to print the data instead of the memory address.

Here is my implementation:

```
class LinkedNode:
    def __init__(self, val, nxt=None):
        self.val = val
        self.nxt = nxt

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new_val):
        node = LinkedNode(new_val, None)
        if self.head:
            curr = self.head
            while curr.nxt:
                curr = curr.nxt
            curr.nxt = node
        else:
            self.head = node

    def print(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            **print(curr.val)**
            curr = curr.nxt


l1 = LinkedList()
l1.append(LinkedNode(2))
l1.append(LinkedNode(3))
l1.append(LinkedNode(4))
l1.print()
```

When the **line** in the print function is "print(curr.val)", the function prints memory addresses. When the **line** is "print(curr.val.val)", the function prints 2,3,4.

Does anyone have a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were passing a `LinkedNode()` object as an argument to `.append()` function:

```
class LinkedNode:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.val = value
        self.nxt = nxt

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new_val):
        node = LinkedNode(new_val, None) #Creation of LinkedNode from integer
        if self.head:
            curr = self.head
            while curr.nxt:
                curr = curr.nxt
            curr.nxt = node
        else:
            self.head = node

    def print(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            print(curr.val)
            curr = curr.nxt


l1 = LinkedList()
l1.append(2) #Argument must be integer, not LinkedNode(integer)
l1.append(3) #Because you are already converting integer to LinkedNode on append function
l1.append(4)
l1.print()
```

> > **Output:**

```
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in these lines you are creating `LinkedNode` objects not values!

```
l1.append(LinkedNode(2))
l1.append(LinkedNode(3))
l1.append(LinkedNode(4))
```

After that, you created a new `LinkedNode(LinkedNode(2), None)` within the scope of the `append` function.

Change it to:

```
l1.append(2)
l1.append(3)
l1.append(4)
```